# How to test the end of an array of unsigned char?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

How can we test the end of an array of unsigned char ? With a string char it's easy, I can just make a test like

```
while (str[i] != '\0')
```

or just

```
while (str[i])
```

But with an array of unsigned char that doesn't work and I don't really understand why. That's an example where I need help

```
BYTE* a = getB();
int i=0;
while(a[i]!=0)
{
    printf("%C", a[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: [This code seems fine](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xoN2so1dCSsRfbM0). What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't. Period.

Comment: Why not choose *one of* C or C++?

Comment: Not "why not" but "you must".

Comment: `%C` is not a valid format specifier for `printf()` in standard C. You should use `%c` instead.

Comment: @MikeCAT As far as I understand it is arbitrary binary data, for which %c specifier will result in junk.

Comment: BTW, this `getB` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @EugeneSh.If what to deal with is arbitary binary data, you won't be ablle to tell the end of array by checking the content, so the length should be passed from `getB()` with the contents.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work for arrays of chars either. I defined `char c[] = {'a', '\0', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};`, that's 7 chars, but you method says it's only 1 char long.

Comment: C does not have a string type. There is no "string char" (none in C++ either). It is all convention. Now think about it. C++ is a **different** language. Pleasse pick **one** of them!

Comment: Your code will work if, and only if, a zero value marks the end of the array. Is that the case? You can solve this however you want, but you must be consistent and use the same method when you generate the data and when you look at it.

Answer (score 8):

**It is completely up to you.**

That is, *you* define what the end of an array means.

Conventionally, sure, the end of a character array is a "null byte", signifiying the terminating position. There's no reason you can't do that with an array of `unsigned char`.

But, just like with `char`, this need not necessarily be the case. Maybe you signify the end of the array by counting its elements (specifying a size), or by declaring that some other character is the final one.

We cannot tell you what that is. Only the person who creates the data (as far as we're concerned here, that's *you*) can do so.

So, either consult the documentation for the library that gave you the array, or reach into your memory. :)

Comment: Just reached into my memory and got a segfault. I knew I should have initialized that pointer at Albuquerque.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value

Answer (score 1):

@eugenesh is right. You can't do do it. Either you need to have extra space at the end and add some kind of delimiter or keep a count of charactera